# What happens when playing Narwhal Torpedo to remove Pandamonium and Tiny Stable?

Tags: unstable-unicorns

In my stable I have 6 unicorn cards and both the Pandamonium and Tiny Stable downgrade cards. I don't have to sacrifice my 6th unicorn because it is considered a panda.) On my turn I play Narwhal Torpedo. What happens first? If Pandamonium is sacrificed first, my unicorns are not pandas so I would have to sacrifice two unicorns.

- **Tiny Stable** (Downgrade card): If at any time you have more than 5 Unicorns in your Stable, SACRIFICE a Unicorn card.
- **Pandamonium** (Downgrade card): All of your Unicorns are considered Pandas. Cards that affect Unicorn cards do not affect your Pandas.
- **Narwhal Torpedo** (Magical Unicorn card): When this card enters your Stable, SACRIFICE all Downgrade cards in your Stable.

And if I only had 5 unicorns and Tiny Stable. When I play Narwhal Tornado, which will activate first?

Comment: All downgrades leave simultaneously.  Checks to see if any unicorns need to be sacrificed do not occur again until after all downgrades are no longer present and as such no unicorns will need to be sacrificed to tiny stable's effect since it is no longer present.

Answer (score 1):

**In this case, you'll keep all of your unicorns.**

Generally, applicable effects all activate simultaneously, and if those effects cause more effects to happen, all those new effects happen simultaneously, and so on. See [The Effect Chain](http://unstablegameswiki.com/index.php?title=UU_Game_Terminology_-_Effects) for full details.

So when you play Narwhal Torpedo, we look to see what needs to happen. You have 7 pandas in your stable, so the only effect happening is the Torpedo entering. That happens, and all of the downgrades are removed simultaneously. Because they're gone, there are no more steps in the chain.

If you didn't have Pandamonium, and you played Narwhal Torpedo as your 6th unicorn, then both it and Tiny Stable would happen at the same time. You'd sacrifice all your downgrades, and a unicorn card.

But let's say that you played White Elephantcorn instead of the Narwhal Torpedo. Its enter ability lets you give away a downgrade. So you play it and trigger its effect, but nothing else happens in this moment because you have 7 pandas. You give away Pandamonium, which causes Tiny Stable's effect to be relevant, and thus there's another link in the effect chain. You have 7 unicorns and Tiny Stable is there, so you have to sacrifice a unicorn. Once that's done, you still have 6, so you have to do it again.